# Which part/step of the TLS handshake is essential for providing PFS?

Tags: tls, rsa, handshake, perfect-forward-secrecy

I would say the key exchange part, because `PFS` is used only during the key exchange of server and client.

Am I right or have I overlooked something?

Comment: Did you mean to tag this with RSA and not DH?

Comment: I was not sure about it

Comment: The point is _erasing all key material that enables decrypting the conversation_.  This can't happen only at the handshake—the handshake, after all, serves to _establish_ the key that the peers can use to decrypt the conversation they're _about to have_; in addition to erasing any secrets that figured into the handshake, they also have to erase that key when the conversation is over.  You might find [an answer over at crypto.SE](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/75025) helpful.